# Error 500 Internal Server error when calling an Azure Function from React

Tags: reactjs, http, azure-functions

When I call my Azure Function from React, it returns a 500 Internal server error. Tried the same thing from Postman and it works fine.

My call from React:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const obj = { name: 'test.jpg' };
    sendRestRequest('GET', `${URL_API_AI_1}`, obj)
  }
```

sendRestRequest method:

```
import request from 'superagent';

export const sendRestRequest = (requestAction, url, body = '') => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request(requestAction, url)
    .send(body)
    .end((error, res) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(res.body);
      }
    });
});
```

Browser error:

```
GET https://"url" 500 (Internal Server Error)
client.js:440 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal Server Error
    at Request.<anonymous> (client.js:440)
    at Request.push../node_modules/component-emitter/index.js.Emitter.emit (index.js:140)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:732)
```

Comment: Are your react app and function both deployed somewhere? Put a `console.log` in the `if (error)` and log out the `res.body` to see if you get any message as to why you got a 500.

Comment: res.body returns null

Answer (score 1):

You would need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for your running azure function.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin.

More info on this from official docs [here](http://Cross-Origin%20Resource%20Sharing%20(CORS)%20is%20a%20mechanism%20that%20uses%20additional%20HTTP%20headers%20to%20tell%20browsers%20to%20give%20a%20web%20application%20running%20at%20one%20origin,%20access%20to%20selected%20resources%20from%20a%20different%20origin.).

To enable CORS from azure portal follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332971/11914067).

To enable CORS for local function testing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750529/11914067).